# Sending a clock over low voltage DC

Tags: voltage, power, pcb-design, analog

I am primarily software. I do debug and test a lot of hardware, so I know enough to be dangerous.

Twenty years ago we built Panasonic-compatible analog-signalling PCBs for controlling Panasonic's line of "hybrid" telephones.

What I remember was that it provided power and signalling over a single pair, much line a telephone line itself if you consider the audio to be the signalling.

I would like to reproduce this configuration with the following specifications: the signalling will be a continuous 50% duty-cycle clock with a possible range of 5 to 20 MHz, the DC supply would be in the range of 9V to 24V, with a maximum of 600ma at 5V needing to be produced at the far end (using a SimpleSwitcher). This would be using a twisted-pair ethernet-style cable.

I was thinking there are probably 10 different ways to accomplish this, and numerous what-ifs are swirling around in my head. But since I've little experience in the analog possibilities, I thought I might ask some experts.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. My main goals are: cheap, simple, hand-solderable, and minimum PCB real estate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Can't you just use 1wire?

Comment: Not sure how well the Dallas 1-wire spec would perform at 50 feet. Do you know?

Comment: It's called Phantom power and, for your application needs filters at both ends.

Comment: I'm not sure how well it'd work either, but it's reportedly a longer-range protocol than I²C. You could also consider a 4-20mA current loop, but that wouldn't be able to provide your 600mA current requirement.

Comment: I am familiar with Phantom Power as a user of audio products, but are you saying there are devices available which I can buy that handle this?

Comment: After reviewing some typical Phantom Power solutions, it seems they all are focused on the 3-wire XLR-type of configuration and very low current.

Comment: Look into [Power Over Ethernet (PoE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet). It has been done 10 different ways and if you are using twisted pair anyway, the mass produced nature of PoE devices and Ethernet cables will likely make this cheaper than anything else.

Comment: @Hearth, good call, 1-wire will do comms with a bus-powered device at well over 50 metres. I've seen it used as such for temperature sensors up ship masts. Miles better than I2C in that regard. Read the Dallas (now Maxim) application notes on it, they talk about 200 m or 750 m with an active pull-up driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phantom power and data: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYCeqP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is some detail missing such as line terminations in case the signalling frequency causes line-reflections.

### EDIT showing a balanced drive

[image]

Comment: This is the sort of starting point I was hoping for. I thought it might be fairly simple. I guess I can determine termination resistance requirements by looking at the signal after 20 feet or so of cable. I guess one of the negative consequences of this is the signal cannot be differential. I thought the original telephone concept had that benefit. Was this due to the use of a special transformer?

Comment: @GaryLa You can certainly make this method differential (just duplicate the filters on the negative rail too). The transformers are for isolation more than anything else in telephone and ethernet systems.

Comment: Would a "Mode A" Power-Over-Ethernet modular jack provide a similar effect?

Comment: There is nothing much in the above circuit that needs to be added other than inductors to make it differential.

Comment: Ethernet - @GaryLa this question is showing signs of moving the goal posts.

Comment: Sort of a mirror image of the supply side with an inductor between the supply and ground, too?

Comment: Yes, I'll make a quick sketch.

Comment: As I said originally, I assumed there were 10 different ways to accomplish this. Not that I need to know them all, I just want to settle on what seems to me to be something I can understand and implement. The Mode A comment was really asking if that's essentially what the Mode A modular jacks are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like the following block diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH14pd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'll leave the details on working it out to you, but simply putting filters where appropriate and adding your clock to the power line should do you fine.

If your circuitry on the receiving end is sufficiently tolerant of input voltage fluctuations, you could even leave off the low-pass filter for the power entirely, though it would increase noise in the circuit and I don't recommend it.

---

As the asker has said they've already worked out this much, I'll give a bit more information.

On the receiving side, you should use an LC input low-pass filter before feeding the voltage into your regulator. I say LC because that gives you lower losses; RC will work as well but provide a harder current limit and will waste some power. An RC filter would be my choice for the high-pass filter, however, since you don't need significant power going through that line.

On the sending end, adding the clock on top of the supply voltage can be done with a simple LC filter like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTHOXa.png)</sup>

There are, needless to say, better ways of doing this, but I think you'd have a hard time finding a much *cheaper* or *easier* way of doing it short of using a resistor instead of an inductor. Again, the choice to use an inductor is to limit power loss. Putting resistors in series with your power source is usually not the best idea.

Comment: I certainly appreciate your effort, but I already have this much figured out. :) But the details are exactly what I was hoping to get some suggestions on.

Comment: @GaryLa I didn't realize you'd already gotten that far. I've added more to the answer, which I think should be enough to make this system work, short of any problems with the clock signal being able to drive the line (you may need an amplifier on it).

Comment: Is it possible it's this simple? That would be great.

Comment: @GaryLa It is indeed this simple! This isn't the *best* way to do it, I'm sure, but it's *a* way to do it that will work. Data integrity will probably be minimally affected, your transmission line itself will be more of a problem than the filters. Of course you'll have to spec your inductors for the full DC current through them that the supply will be providing, and you'll want to avoid resonances, but those are just details.